# Problem margin/padding for DialogFragment after implementing the new API SplashScreen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-actionbar, padding

I added the new Splashscreen API (androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-rc01) on my app, after that my margins/paddings are broken but only for my launcher activity (MainActivity) especially for dialog fagments opened from this activity. In other activities, no problem, everything is working fine.

Below, my dialog fragment without the Splashscreen implemented, my paddings/margins are OK :
[image: Margin and padding OK without Splashscreen]

And now with Splashscreen implementation :

[[image: Margin and padding broken withSplashscreen2]

I followed instructions from the developer Android doc here : https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen

In my MainActivy.kt

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```

In the Manifest.xml, I added the code below in my MainActity

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppStarting"
```

In my Splashscreen theme, I have set the "postSplashScreenTheme" to my original theme

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppStarting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground</item>
</style>
```

And to finish, my dialog fragment is the same XML using everywhere in my app with padding in a RelativeLayout :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
```

This problem is only for DialogFragment or AlertDialog in the MainActivity, no problem for the other components or DialogFragment in other activities...
Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. All paddings even inside EditTextfields were gone.
In my case it was fitsSystemWindows set to true in the postSplashScreenTheme.

Setting

```
fitsSystemWindows = false
```

solved the problem for me.

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot ! I tried a lot of things with this "fitsSystemWindows" parameter but I didn't try to set it in my original theme... It's working fine now !

Answer (score 0):

Hiede's solution did not work for me at first. I need to change the parent to match my Material3 and add the item

```
 <style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen.IconBackground">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/bg_splash</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground</item>
    <!-- Set the theme of the Activity that directly follows splash screen. -->
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/postSplashTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="postSplashTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">false</item>
</style>
```